# how to add radio button in django admin model

Tags: django-models

Does Django itself provide radio button models? I was trying to find out how to make radio buttons in Django admin, but since there is nothing related to that, It seems like Django doesn't have radio buttons as default.

Answer (score 0):

A radiobutton is not a modelField but a form widget for the ChoiceField. Like for example:

`forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify radio_fields provided by admin like in this example:

> radio_fields = {
> "gender": admin.VERTICAL,
> "document_type": admin.VERTICAL,
> }

where gender and document_type are fields (foreign key or choices).